# Error AADSTS900561, getting current userinformation in Graph and RestClint

Tags: c#, graph, office365, .net-4.5, desktop-application

For my desktop application i'm working on, I need to get the current userinformation.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me is a GET but when requesting this, error occured:

[image]

The code I'm using:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient($"{tokenEndpoint}");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
request.Method = Method.POST;

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.AddParameter("client_id", txtClientId.Text, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("scope", "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("code", code, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("redirect_uri", redirectUrl, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "authorization_code", ParameterType.GetOrPost);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    TokenData tokenData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenData>(response.Content);
    if (tokenData != null)
    {
        RestClient graphClient = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        var grRequest = new RestRequest();
        grRequest.Method = Method.GET;
        grRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", $"{tokenData.token_type} " + tokenData.access_token);
        grRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

        var grResponse = client.Execute(grRequest);
        if (grResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            //AADSTS900561 occured.
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thank's in advance.

Comment: By using a POST request instead of a GET request, it literally says that in the error. `grRequest.Method = Method.GET;` should be `POST`, and you need to include a request body.

Comment: Thnx, but the method i'm calling is a GET, when I changed this to POST then other error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Found it...  use:

```
var grResponse = grClient.Execute(grRequest);
```

instead of:

```
var grResponse = client.Execute(grRequest);
```